# make promise.all wait until both API's are done before it completes

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have a profile that is doing this..

```
Promise.all([this.fetchInsights(), this.fetchTouchpoints()])
     .then(([insights, touchpoints]) =>
       console.log(insights, touchpoints)
     )
```

Here is the `fetchInsights()`

```
fetchInsights = () => {
  fetch('API_URL' + this.queryParams.custId + '/' + this.queryParams.acctNo, {
    method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
};
```

Here is the `fetchTouchpoints()`

```
  fetchTouchpoints = () => {
    fetch('API_URL' + this.queryParams.custId + '/' + this.queryParams.acctNo, {
      method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res2 => res2.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  };
```

When I run this, the page reads undefined, undefined right away. This is because insights and touchpoints are both undefined since the API's calls are not finished.

When I look at the log in Eclipse (this is a Springboot app), I see that the response is both successful and it prints out the response in console there... but the app doesn't update.

How can I make it so that Promise.all prints the log AFTER both API calls are done?

I tried putting `Promise.all` in `componentDidMount` and in `render()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Your `fetchX` functions do not `return` the promises they are creating, so `Promise.all` waits for nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return the promises.

Btw, for code readability, use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Here is the fixed `fetchInsights`:

```
fetchInsights = () => {
  return fetch(`API_URL${this.queryParams.custId}/${this.queryParams.acctNo}`, {
    method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
};
```

Comment: what is the best way to seperate the responses in Promise.all? insiead of then([1, 1]) how can I do the first response, and then the second?

Comment: If you depend on the response of the first one, you could call the second one in the `.then` of the first one.

Or you write an async function and use `await fetch...`